# Is it possible to select multiple lines of codes in Jupyter notebook and convert them all to Markdown?

Tags: markdown

Is it possible to select multiple lines in Jupyter notebook and convert them all to Markdown? I know how to convert one cell individually, but converting them in a batch would save time.

Comment: Is there some distinguishing feature of all the targeted lines that can allow it to be programmatic? If so, .. I think for in batch, you'll want to run the code from a new notebook or in a Python script and use `nbformat`.  I have a number of examples using it that can be found [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/search?q=nbformat%20markdown%20%40fomightez%20order%3Alatest) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3a8508004%20nbformat).

Comment: Even if not a distinguishing feature, you could work through them and collect the specific cell numbers and lines and still use nbformat to process *en masse*. The code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004) might give you a vague idea how you could plug in such information to process your notebooks.