# Is it possible to create a new jupyter notebook with a selection of cells on a notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cell

Is it possible to create a new jupyter notebook with a selection of cells on a notebook ?

Comment: This is covered under the section 'Making a notebook from a block of cells at a start point & spanning n number of cells' [in  answer to 'Jupyter notebook, move cells from one notebook into a new notebook' here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004). If you aren't trying to do this programmatically and a looking for something more 'drag-and-dop' that you do by hand, see about 'Use JupyterLab to drag by hand a sequence of cells to a new notebook' at the bottom of my answer there.