# Using jupyter notebook tags with IPython.display to execute a specific cell

Tags: javascript, python, conditional-statements, tags, jupyter

I want to use the following code to execute a cell depending on a tag in jupyter notebook :

from IPython.display import Javascript

for i,v in **column_name.items()**:

```
if "x" in v:
    Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([4])")

elif "y" in v:
    Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([3])")

elif "z" in v:
    Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([2])")

else:
    Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([1])")*
```

Since the entire notebook is actually very long and I don't have the cells numbers, I want to use the cell tag feature to add a number to the cells and be able to reference it in the loop above.

Basically, if you can find people with x in v, execute cell tagged "4"

Is it possible  to reference the tagged number of a cell in the loop ? which would mean :

for i,v in **column_name.items()**:

```
if "x" in v:
    Javascript("Jupyter.notebook.execute_cells([**"number of the tag"**])")
```

I tried tagging the cells I wanted with a number (example below is with 2) and then telling Ipython.display to execute this cell if there were people in the z category.

[Tagged cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0fUCY.png)

Comment: This isn't how Jupyter is meant to be used and I suspect isn't going to work in current versions. (So one update and you are out of luck.) Or you send it to someone and they attempt to use and cannot.  You may want to design something less brittle. This has the hallmarks of you making [an XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) here. There's probably a more standard way to run this. Think of using a traditional, portable script and how you'd approach it in that case. That being said, if you really wanted to pursue your idea, you can write another notebook or script to use Python, particulalry...

Comment: <continued> nbformat (see mention [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76591105/8508004) about nbformat for a vaguely related idea) read your unrun notebook with some sort of placeholder for the cell numbers and tags that it can parse and fill in the numbers based on the tags. And then you can run the new version of the notebook file.

Comment: Hi Wayne, thanks for your advice, I'll try to do it in a more conventional (simple) way by adding it in a classical if/else . I was worried that the conditional code might be too long because the code to execute in each case is a bit long, but I guess it will be more robust this way. If it doesn't work I'll look into nbformat.

Comment: And keep in mind if it is about keeping the notebook clean of code, you can put the code in a separate `.py` (or `.ipy`) file and run that in the same namespace as the notebook with `%run -i my_script.py`. (The `-i` flag lets it run interactively so anything already defined in the notebook is available to the code in the script.) I know that adds another file to keep track of but can be useful and can make developing easier as you can use your own code editor. Alternatively, there are ways like using Voila that those interacting with your notebook wouldn't see the code anyway.