# How to use function from 1 jupyter notebook in another jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

There are two python notebooks:

- `trading.ipynb` (1st)
- `monitorTrades.ipynb` (2nd)

While the execution of the main block is in the first notebook, a function has to be executed in the second notebook (at the same time). This function must have 2 arguments (which are calculated during the execution in first notebook).

There are multiple functions in `monitorTrades.ipynb`, but I only want to run function: `checkFunc()`.
This function has 4 arguments. 2 of which came from `monitorTrades.ipynb` and the other 2 arguments are calculated during the execution of `trading.ipynb`.

The function must execute on `monitorTrades.ipynb`.

How to do this implement this?

Comment: See [link](https://saturncloud.io/blog/how-to-import-functions-from-another-jupyter-notebook/) on using the %run command in Jupyter.

Comment: i know about that but I don't want to import the function I want that the function should run on the same notebook but it should be executed by another notebook along with arguments

Comment: I am trying to find any work arounds if there are any

Comment: I suspect `%run -i` or importing the notebook (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58086016/8508004) or [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/package-for-importing-jupyter-notebooks-as-modules/12923/2?u=fomightez)) that user19077881 is indicating is probably the best way in the long run even if you need to re-design things some. However, there are alternatives if you want to make it more complex. You can use papermill or nbformat or sed for find/replace to target the other notebook and share or inject variables, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76591105/8508004).

Comment: I'll suggest you can probably search around [the Jupyter Discourse Forum using 'importnb' as a keyword](https://discourse.jupyter.org/search?q=importnb%20order%3Alatest) and/or ['papermill' as search term](https://discourse.jupyter.org/search?q=papermill%20order%3Alatest) to get other related advice and options.

Comment: Thanks @Wayne for your suggestions however for my use case that won't work. However, I have got an ugly workaround since its little urgent I would go with that solution only. Thanks though for giving it a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I have tried to find the solution and have tried multiple things but I didn't got the solution i was looking for so I have built a workaround for this problem.

trading.ipynb

I made a function to write these values in a csv.

```
import os
import csv

def write_target_sl(value1: float, value2: float) -> None:

file_path = f"monitor.csv"


try:
    with open(file_path, 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        header = next(reader)
        data = list(reader)  
except FileNotFoundError:
    data = []


with open(file_path, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=header)
    writer.writeheader()      
    writer.writerow({'Value1': float(value1), 'value2': float(value2)})
    
    if data:
        
        data = data[1:]            
        writer.writerows(dict(row[:2]) for row in data)
```

This function will overwrite the same row in csv file.

Now in monitorTrades.ipynb

I made these functions:

```
import csv
import time

def check_csv_for_changes():

filename = "monitor.csv" 
previous_values = None

while True:
    try:
        with open(filename, "r") as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
            next(reader)  
            row = next(reader)  
            current_values = float(row[0]), float(row[1])

            if current_values != previous_values:
                
                previous_values = current_values
                handle_new_values(current_values[0], current_values[1])  

    except FileNotFoundError:
        print(f"CSV file not found: {filename}")

    time.sleep(50)  # Check every 50 seconds

def handle_new_values(value1, value2):

   print(f"Values changed, new values are value1 {value1}, value2 {value2}")



 check_csv_for_changes()
```

Now this does solve my problem. Well if someone faces this kind of problem then yeah you can use it to solve.

Please drop solution to this if someone has one.

Thanks for all the comments.

Comment: I suspect you could probably improve the explanation of the logic of the solution better. Normally, `%store` would be used in Jupyter for this sort of thing if I am understanding, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47707020/8508004). Or maybe pickling and reading in the pickled data? Your approach makes the data more human readable and portable beyond Python though. I think not clearly describing what you were trying to do without digging into your code made it hard to give you advice and I think your solution post here continues that trend. Abstract things out and generalize more.

Comment: I will try to explain it. I needed to pass 2 arguments from trading.ipynb to monitorTrades.ipynb. Then, there is a function in monitorTrades.ipynb that requires 4 args 2 from trading.ipynb and 2 from monitorTrades.ipynb itself. Also, this function has to be run in monitorTrades.ipynb. So, in my solution i used a csv file to pass these 2 arguments and then monitorTrades.ipynb has the function shown for retrieving those values. I hope I could make it somewhat understandable @Wayne. Thanks.

Comment: I meant to suggest improving your posted solution with those details. Something to consider as a general guide to writing good solutions is to write an answer for yourself six months or a year when you may be facing a similar issue in a different context. Because the person you help may be future you.

Comment: Oh okay! Thanks for the suggestion will update it