# Executing Jupyter Notebook with variables from a csv file

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a code block resembling below and a bunch of cells below using this event.

```
event = MyEvent({
    "city": "CAN",
    "servicenow_id": "123456",
    "devices": ["can-1-server-1"],
    "workflow_name": "PYTHON_WORKER",
    })
```

I have an another csv where there is a mapping of City, ServiceNow, devices exist. How do i reuse this jupyternotebook while passing different city, servicenowid and devices for each execution. I have explored papermill and tagging to start with.

Explored papermill [and tagging to start with.](https://github.com/nteract/papermill/blob/main/README.md)

Comment: "I have explored papermill and tagging to start with." And how were they not doing what you need? You can also just make a 'template' notebook with placeholders  and then from a 'control notebook' use find and replace to fill in the values and then execute the produced `.ipynb` files with `jupyter nbconvert` or `jupytext`. In place of the template with placeholders you can also use code and use nbformat to make the notebook with the code with the substitutions you need. Somebody recently posted a more convoluted usage than yours and so what was discussed there may help? See ...

Comment: <continued> [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77837807/8508004). [Here](https://github.com/fomightez/pdbsum-binder/blob/b675978ad9034f6a807677c6079d2ddbb1f89a70/notebooks/Snakefile#L140C1-L143C12) is an example where I use a Snakefile as the 'control' layer and it includes a stub of the notebook as text and then in a step I save that template content as a python with the appropriate content and names from the information in the control layer and then use jupytext to both convert the script to notebooks and run it at the same time.

Comment: <continued>  Others [like Ploomber](https://engine.ploomber.io/en/latest/howto/pass-objects.html).