# How to copy a cell from one jupyter notebook to another in Jupyter Notebook 7?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I want to copy several cells from one Notebook to another one in Jupyter Notebook 7.

I have tried the methods found in the forum, such as shift + up/down key to select and cmd + C /cmd + V to copy and paste between two notbeooks. But they do not work in Jupypter Notebook 7.

I am using mac OS 14.1 with Google Chrome.

Comment: As noted [here a month ago](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/7041#issuecomment-1726781091) by Jeremy Howard, this is currently a known issue. You have a couple of options at this time for a work around. You can do it programmatically using `nbformat`. Or with the JupyterLab interface you can click and drag. Both of these are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71244733/8508004). As far as using JupyterLab, it is easy to run full JupyterLab without installing anything at all on your computer. For using JupyterLab in a browser without installing anything more, you have at....

Comment: <continued> least two options for that right now. Go to [here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and click on the blue-green colored text in the upper left side that says 'JupyterLab' next to the '`Open demo in new tab`' text. Get your `.ipynb` your files into virtual-like Jupyter session running in your browser on your own computer, by dragging-and-dropping them into the file navigation panel on the left. Do the moving/copying using JupyterLab's ability to open multiple `.ipynb` files and arrange them side-by-side by clicking and dragging on the tab with the name. After ...

Comment: <continued> editing you can 'download' the files back to the preferred location on your machine by right-clicking the name of the file in the file navigator and selecting to Download. (I know it seems weird but as of now the Jupyter session that is running in like in a virtual system in your browser and so it is best to think of it as a remote machine, even though it is in your browser on your owm machine thanks to being Web Assembly (WASM)-based.)

Comment: <continued> (2) Go [here](https://github.com/binder-examples/requirements) and press '`launch binder`' to get an anonymous **temporary** JupyterLab session with full Python and Jupyter running on a remote machine, i.e., not JupyterLite. (You can pretty much use most MyBinder sessions if you know how to open them as JupyterLab or know how to switch to that interface by editing the URL.) You can drag-and-drop the notebook files from your local machine into file panel on the left to get them on the remote machine and then do the editing. ...

Comment: <continued> You can arrange the two notebooks (or different view of same notebook) side-by-side by in JupyterLab by opening them both (or selecting a new view of the same notebook while click on the tab) and then clicking and dragging the tabs to arrange them in the main view panel. Once you complete editing, you can download the files back to the preferred location on your machine by right-clicking the name of the file in the file navigator and selecting to Download from the remote computer back to your local machine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed explanation.